# Effect of 90 degree head angle (vertical steering axis) - zero flop

Tags: geometry, steering

Are there any two-wheel bicycles with 90 degree head angle? The trail would be determined by fork offset alone, i.e. it would be a caster wheel.

Related:

- [What effect does head tube angle have on a bicycle?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/12837/what-effect-does-head-tube-angle-have-on-a-bicycle)
- [Desirable maximum steering angle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/50381/desirable-maximum-steering-angle)

---

Edit

- Adjustable Geometry Bike

  - [Photos](https://www.flickr.com/photos/78152658@N05/albums/72157664509440673)
  - [Interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3o1WkW3Dps)
  - Results?
- https://www.bikeradar.com/news/this-part-wooden-enduro-bike-features-an-adjustable-head-angle/

  - Results?
- https://moorepants.github.io/dissertation/parameterstudy.html#geometric-variation

---

Edit

- [Handling Stability Parameters](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/43564/handling-stability-parameters)
- [Understanding the bike geometry through riding](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/35043/understanding-the-bike-geometry-through-riding)
- [What makes a bike stay upright when moving?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4656/what-makes-a-bike-stay-upright-when-moving/)

The first bicycles ([velocipede/penny-farthing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle#History)) had a steep steering angle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle#/media/File:Michauxjun.jpg

Video: [How to ride a penny-farthing](https://youtu.be/p--RKyDFIAk?t=46)

Comment: Artistic cycling bikes are very close to 90, though maybe just a bit shy of that: https://cimg1.ibsrv.net/gimg/bikeforums.net-vbulletin/2000x1504/art2_fda8295a8f04a178ab8a9eabe47029aef2605de2.jpg

Comment: Are the links related to question or necessary?

Comment: @ojs What are you suggesting? Should I remove valuable references or move them to a non-answer?

Comment: Start a blog and post the collection of links there? Some explanation what the links are and why you think they are related would be helpful too.